# private variable declaration in TypeScript constructor to induce DI

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dependency-injection

To introduce Dependency Injection in Angular 2 using TypeScript, we use the code as below:

```
constructor(private _service : SampleService){}
```

I would like to know the importance of `private` keyword in the declaration of variable here. Will it impact if we don't declare the service a `private`?

Thanks

Comment: you should look into what the access modifiers do. http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`constructor(private _service : SampleService){}` is the recommended way to inject a service that you wish to use in the component.

If you do not use `private`, you will have to write more lines of code to access the injected service outside the constructor like below:

```
class CompClass {
  private _service: SampleService;
  constructor(service : SampleService) {
    this._service = service;
  }

  doSomething() : void {
    this._service.makeServiceCall();
  }
}
```